# Reading large file, splitting by new line

Tags: performance, .net, vb.net

I am reading a ~120 MB log file (~300 Million lines of text).

```
... 
30/05/2014 15:07:18 0000030-0000738 Net SourceID 11000006
30/05/2014 15:07:18 0000030-0000738 Communication RouteID 108
30/05/2014 15:14:44 0000030-0002027 Communication Route_Complete  Already Completed
30/05/2014 15:07:40 0000030-0000739 Communication RouteID Selected 108
...
```

Each line is created programatically, so the `MakeLogLine` function can extract the exact information needed.

#### MakeLogLine

```
Private Function MakeLogLine(ByVal l As String, Optional ByVal lineNum As Integer = 0) As LogLine

    ' Trim any leading / trailing whitespace.'
    l = l.Trim()

    ' Extracts route Id separately to keep track of the ones that have been tagged.'
    Dim rid As String = ExtractRouteId(l)

    If rid IsNot Nothing Then
        Call Me.linesWithRouteIds.Add(New rIdLines With {.line = line, .rid = rid})
    End If

    Return New LogLine With {.lstr = l,
                             .threadId = ExtractThreadId(l),
                             .requestId = ExtractRequestId(l),
                             .lineNum = lineNum,
                             .sourceId = ExtractSourceId(l),
                             .performanceId = ExtractPerformanceId(l),
                             .routeId = rid,
                             .methodName = ExtractMethodName(l),
                             .time = ExtractTime(l)}
End Function
```

#### ExtractRouteId

An example of how I extract the text from the line.

```
Private Function ExtractRouteId(ByVal l As String) As String
    Dim rid As String

    If l.Length < 59 Then Return Nothing

    rid = l.Substring(50)

    If rid.Length < "RouteID X".Length Then Return Nothing
    If Not rid(0) = "R"c Then Return Nothing
    If Not rid(5) = "I"c Then
        ' Catches Route_Completed .. lines.'
        Return Nothing
    End If

    ' Assume its a RouteID by this stage.'

    ' Trim the RouteID from the string.'
    rid = rid.Substring(8, rid.Length - 8)

    ' For RouteID Selected.'
    Try
        If rid.Length > 8 AndAlso rid(0) = "S"c Then Return rid.Substring(9, rid.Length - 9)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return rid
    End Try

    Return rid

End Function
```

#### GetAllLines

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets all the lines in the file at the path, puts them in the list of lines.
''' </summary>
''' <returns>True if successful, false if not.</returns>
Public Function GetAllLines() As Boolean
    If Not CheckFile() Then Return Nothing

    Const MaxLineSize As Integer = 1024 * 4
    Dim buffer(MaxLineSize - 1) As Char
    Dim charCount As Integer
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(62)
    Dim Split As String()
    Dim lineNum As Integer = 0
    ' Create a new list of log lines.'
    Me.lines = New List(Of LogLine)

    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(Me.filename)

        Do Until reader.EndOfStream
            'Read the next blocksize(4)KB of the file.'
            charCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, MaxLineSize)

            With builder
                Call .Clear()
                Call .Append(buffer, 0, charCount)

                If charCount = MaxLineSize Then
                  'Read up to the next line break and append to the block just read.'
                    Call .Append(reader.ReadLine())
                End If

                Split = .ToString.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))
            End With

            For LineNo As Integer = 0 To Split.Length - 1
                Call Me.lines.Add(MakeLogLine(Split(LineNo), lineNum))
                lineNum += 1
            Next
        Loop
    End Using

    ' Successful.'
    Return True
End Function
```

**My Current Run times:**

For a 120MB file, with 2,076,313 lines is 7.2 seconds.
For a 200MB file, with 3,357,072 lines is 12.4 seconds.

**GetAllLines**

I am reading the file in chunks then appending new lines where necessary.
This is the fastest way I have found.

But 7 Seconds is still too slow.

How can I improve on this?

**ExtractRouteId**

I am trying to eliminate as many calculations as possible, but is there any way I can improve upon this?

Comment: I'm not sure what it would do for speed, but any reason you're not using the [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: You don't need to write Call

Comment: @the_lotus why do I not need to write Call?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have just tested the ReadLine method and the performance decreases by 0.5s for the 120MB file and .8s for the 200MB file.

Comment: "Performance Decreased" as in it got 0.5 faster or slower?  Also, when doing so did you eliminate the StringBuilder?  Purely using `ReadLine` should mean you can get away without using it

Comment: @JamesThorpe 0.5s slower. I've added the code to the question.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. Please see the meta question: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Good**

The shortcircuit condition aka `AndAlso` is used.
The `StreamReader` is enclosed inside a `using` statement.
Magic numbers are hidden behind const.
`StringBuilder` is constructed using a initial size.

**Bad**
`StringBuilder` is constructed using a initial size which is not high enough.
Using of Call, which is kept only for backward compatibility.
Returning `Nothing` instead of `False` (GetAllLines).
Returning `Nothing` instead of `String.Empty` (ExtractRouteId).
Using of single character parameters.

**Inconsistent parameter naming**
Sometimes `camelCased` which is the right choice regarding the naming convention, but sometime `PascalCased` which is wrong for parameters/variables.

**Refactoring**

Let us start with the `GetAllLines()` method. If we read the methodname we would expect that the method will return lines, but instead it returns `True` or `Nothing`.
So for testing purpose we should change the return type to a `List(Of LogLine)` and add an inputparameter `fileName As String`. In this way the method won't be coupled tightly to the `Me` object what as a guess will be a form.
<s>The variable `lineNum` is only used to count the added `LogLines` which is useless, so let us remove it.</s>
As we use `Split = .ToString.Split(CChar(Environment.NewLine))` at each iteration of the `Do until` loop, we should extract `CChar(Environment.NewLine)` somehow outside the loop.
We should also rename the array `Split` to something more meaningful and something which isn't a known methodname.
Removing the `With builder .. End With` will save us one indentionlevel which makes our code more readable.
Last the `CheckFile()` method should be renamed to `IsFileValid()` and should have an inputparameter `fileName As String`.

```
Public Function GetAllLines(fileName As String) As List(Of LogLine)

    Dim logLines As New List(Of LogLine)()

    If Not CheckFile(fileName) Then Return logLines

    Const MaxLineSize As Integer = 4096
    Const stringBuilderCapacity As Integer = 8192
    Dim buffer(MaxLineSize - 1) As Char
    Dim charCount As Integer
    Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(stringBuilderCapacity)
    Dim singleLines As String()
    Dim newLineChars As Char() = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()
    Dim lineNumber As Integer = 0

    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fileName)
        Do Until reader.EndOfStream  

            charCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, MaxLineSize)
            builder.Append(buffer, 0, charCount)

            If reader.Peek() >= 0 Then
                builder.Append(reader.ReadLine())
            End If

            singleLines = builder.ToString().Split(newLineChars)

            For Each singleLine As String In singleLines
                logLines.Add(MakeLogLine(singleLine, lineNumber))
                lineNumber += 1
            Next
            builder.Clear()
        Loop
    End Using

    Return logLines
End Function
```

Now let us take a look at the `ExtractRouteId()` method.
We will for readability change the name of the inputparameter to `currentLine`.
For the same purpose we will rename `rid` to `routeId`.
As we could count the length of `RouteID X` by hand, we should create a const out of our result and use it, but as we return `String.Empty` if the `Length < 59` we won't need to check if `rid.Length < "RouteID X"` at all as this will be true.

We are only interested in the part of the string which starts at an specified index, so we can use the overloaded `SubString()` method which takes only the startindex and returns the string starting at this index till the end.

```
Private Const minRouteIdLength As Integer = 9
Private Function ExtractRouteId(ByVal currentLine As String) As String
    Dim routeId As String = String.Empty

    If currentLine.Length < 59 OrElse _
       Not (currentLine(50) = "R"c) OrElse _
       Not (currentLine(55) = "I"c) Then
        Return routeId
    End If

    routeId = currentLine.Substring(58)

    If routeId.Length > minRouteIdLength AndAlso routeId(0) = "S"c Then
        routeId = routeId.Substring(minRouteIdLength)
    End If

    Return routeId
End Function
```

As I need to leave the office now, I will just place the `MakeLogLine()` method here and will add some explanation tomorrow.

```
Private Function MakeLogLine(ByVal currentLine As String, Optional lineNumber As Integer = 0) As LogLine

    currentLine = currentLine.Trim()

    ' Extracts route Id separately to keep track of the ones that have been tagged.'
    Dim routeId As String = ExtractRouteId(currentLine)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(routeId) Then
        Me.linesWithRouteIds.Add(New rIdLines With {.line = line, .rid = routeId})
    End If

    Return New LogLine With {.lstr = currentLine,
                             .threadId = ExtractThreadId(currentLine),
                             .requestId = ExtractRequestId(currentLine),
                             .lineNum = lineNumber,
                             .sourceId = ExtractSourceId(currentLine),
                             .performanceId = ExtractPerformanceId(currentLine),
                             .routeId = routeId ,
                             .methodName = ExtractMethodName(currentLine),
                             .time = ExtractTime(currentLine)}
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going through everything!

Could you tell me the advantage of using **String.IsNullOrEmpty** and **String.empty**, over **Nothing**.

I have also optimized the other functions based on your above recommendations, although I was struggling to see how I could improve **ExtractTime**, could you please have a look above?
Thankyou! ~Harry

Comment: @Mumf For a string this does't do any difference, but for keeping the code consistent, as you e.g can't have a 'Nothing' as a boolean like in the `GetAllLines()` method.